# why auto_increment value adding by 2 for single table in mysql

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have more than 20 tables in my schema. Every table has auto_increment id and its adding value by 1 like 1,2,3 but only single table called "member_table" is adding by 2 like 2,4,6.

Even I have done

```
SET GLOBAL auto_increment_increment=1;
SET GLOBAL auto_increment_offset  = 1;
```

But still the same table adding by 2.

Why this happen ? I ever seen like this problem.

Comment: How do you add values? Post your code. Maybe you add twice and second row is discarded

Comment: Second do you restart server after setting `SET GLOBAL`  or tried inserting using new connection?

Comment: @lad2025 I dint restart the server but i Just closed the workbench and opened and inserted.

Comment: It can happen if the code tries to insert a row twice and an `UNIQUE` index prevents the second insertion. The auto incremented column is incremented on each `INSERT` attempt, no matter if the `INSERT` is successful or not.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

`SET @@auto_increment_increment=1;
SET @@auto_increment_offset=1;`